# Looking for documentation or source for CERN Fortran programming aids

Tags: programming, identify-this-software, reference-request, fortran

In the 1970s, the CERN Program Library for IBM/CDC included a few FORTRAN source analysis tools. As mentioned in [CERN Computer Newsletter 141](https://cds.cern.ch/record/1292454/files/n-141.pdf),

```
Q.      SERVICE OR HOUSEKEEPING-PROGRAMMING AIDS
...
*X  Q800   FLODIA    Flow diagram program for Fortran programs
*   Q900   TIDY      Cleaning up Fortran programs
```

These two programs, along with the program `FLOWER`, also a flow diagram generator, survive in the BESM-6 version of the CERN library. However, the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20000621023835/http://wwwinfo.cern.ch/asdoc/Welcome.html) for these programs is missing, no `Q800` or `Q900` there.

Does anyone remember using these programs or know how to locate the documentation, or, ideally, the source? What was the feature set of those programs?

---

Experimenting revealed that giving a simple Fortran program as input to `FLODIA` produces

```
 СОL.73-80                                              СОL. 1-72                                             FLОW DIАGRАМ

                         РRОGRАМ МАIN
                         INТЕGЕR РRIМЕ
                         DIМЕNSIОN РRIМЕ(90)
                 -------
                 I       DО 1 N=2,100
                 I    1  РRIМЕ(N) = 1
                 -------
                --------
                I        DО 2 N=2,100
                I        IF(РRIМЕ(N)) 2, 2, 22
                I  С-      .
                I  С-        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   GО ТО    2    ------
                I  С-          - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -   GО ТО   22    ---  V
                I  С-                                                                        V  V
                I  С-    -                                     ---(  ---(  ---(  ---(    22---  V
                I    22  L=100/N                                                                V
                I-------                                                                        V
                II       DО 3 К=2,L                                                             V
                II       РRIМЕ(N*К) = 0                                                         V
                II    3  СОNТINUЕ                                                               V
                I-------                                                                        V
                I  С-    -                                     ---(  ---(  ---(  ---(     2------
                I     2  СОNТINUЕ
                --------
                 -------
                 I       DО 4 N=2,100
                 I       IF(РRIМЕ(N).ЕQ.1) РRINТ 5,N
                 I    4  СОNТINUЕ
                 -------
                      5  FОRМАТ (1ХI6)
                         SТОР
                         ЕND
```

along with some cryptic tables, and `FLOWER` outputs

```
                                                                              РRОGRАМ МАIN   РАGЕ NО    1
                                        INТЕGЕR РRIМЕ
                                        DIМЕNSIОN РRIМЕ(100)

                                        -----------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------*  DО  1      N=2,100                   *
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                                                        I
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    1  +++I   РRIМЕ(N)=1                          I
                                        -----------------------------------------
                                                           I
                                        -----------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------*  DО  2      N=2,100                   *
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                                                        I
  +                                                        .
  +                                                    . ’   ’ .
  +                                                . ’    IF     ’ .
  +                                            . ’ (РRIМЕ(N))        ’ .
  +                                        --’ .                       . ’--
  +                                        I     ’ .               . ’     I
  +                                        I         ’ .       . ’         I
  +                                        I             ’ . ’             I
  +                                        I -             I 0             I +
  +                                     -------         -------            I
  +                                     *2    *         *2    *            I
  +                                      ’. .’           ’. .’             I
  +                                        ’               ’               I
  +                                                                        I
  +                                                        I----------------
  +                                                        I
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                              22     I   L=100/N                             I
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                                                        I
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +-------------------------------------*  DО  3      К=2,L                     *
  +I                                    -----------------------------------------
  +I                                                       I
  +I                                    -----------------------------------------
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    3  +++I   РRIМЕ(N*К)=0                        I
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                                                        I
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    2  ++++++++++++++++++СОNТINUЕ
                                                           I
                                        -----------------------------------------
  --------------------------------------*  DО  4      N=2,100                   *
  +                                     -----------------------------------------
  +                                                        I
  +                                                        .
  +                                                    . ’   ’ .
  +                               4                . ’    IF     ’ .       FАLSЕ
  +                                            . ’ ((((((((((((((((( ’ .
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  ’ . ((((((((((((((((((((( . ’------------------
                                                 ’ . ((((((((((((((. ’                     I
                                                     ’ .       . ’                         I
                                                         ’ . ’                             I
                                                           I ТRUЕ                          I
                                                           I                               I
                                          (РRIМЕ(N).ЕQ.1) РRINТ 5,N                        I
                                                           I                               I
                                                           ---------------------------------
                                                           I
                                  5     FОRМАТ (1ХI6)                                                     **
                                                           I
                                                                              РRОGRАМ МАIN   РАGЕ NО    2
                                                           I
                                                      ***********
                                                      *  SТОР   *
                                                      *         *
                                                      ***********
```

`TIDY` appears to renumber the labels and move the `FORMAT` specifiers to the end of the program:

```
       * Т I D У *                                                             РАGЕ   1
                                        РRОGRАМ МАIN

    1        РRОGRАМ МАIN
    2        INТЕGЕR РRIМЕ
    3        DIМЕNSIОN РRIМЕ(90)
    4        DО 1 N=2,100
    5     1  РRIМЕ(N) = 1
    6        DО 2 N=2,100
    7        IF(РRIМЕ(N)) 2, 2, 22
    8    22  L=100/N
    9        DО 3 К=2,L
   10        РRIМЕ(N*К) = 0
   11     3  СОNТINUЕ
   12     2  СОNТINUЕ
   13        DО 4 N=2,100
   14        IF(РRIМЕ(N).ЕQ.1) РRINТ 5,N
   15     5  FОRМАТ (1ХI6)
   16     4  СОNТINUЕ
   17        SТОР
   18        ЕND
       * Т I D У *                                                             РАGЕ   2
                                        РRОGRАМ МАIN

             РRОGRАМ МАIN                                                        А    1
             INТЕGЕR РRIМЕ                                                       А    2
             DIМЕNSIОN РRIМЕ(90)                                                 А    3
             DО 1 N=2,100                                                        А    4
        1    РRIМЕ(N)=1                                                          А    5
             DО 4 N=2,100                                                        А    6
             IF (РRIМЕ(N)) 4,4,2                                                 А    7
        2    L=100/N                                                             А    8
             DО 3 К=2,L                                                          А    9
             РRIМЕ(N*К)=0                                                        А   10
        3    СОNТINUЕ                                                            А   11
        4    СОNТINUЕ                                                            А   12
             DО 5 N=2,100                                                        А   13
             IF (РRIМЕ(N).ЕQ.1) РRINТ 6, N                                       А   14
        5    СОNТINUЕ                                                            А   15
             SТОР                                                                А   16
       С                                                                         А   17
        6    FОRМАТ (1ХI6)                                                       А   18
             ЕND                                                                 А   19
```

Comment: Interesting find. Do you plan to make them accessible? I'd love to have a look at FLOWER.

Comment: @Raffzahn There are only binary object modules. While I should attach the volume image with the library containing them, to [my online emulator](https://mailcom.com/besm6/runitnew.cgi), the best way is to build and install [the emulator](https://github.com/besm6/dispak) locally. Many years ago I posted a long how-to description to the Classic-Mainframes group on Yahoo (although it could have been for the SIMH emulator rather than the user mode emulator), but Yahoo groups are long gone.

Comment: See also FORFLO, a similar flow-charting program for the PDP-10: [documentation](https://saildart.org/FORFLO.HLP[F4,REG]), [source](https://saildart.org/FORFLO.MAC[F4,REG]), [example output](https://www.saildart.org/CON.LST[1,LMM]) for [original code](https://www.saildart.org/CON.F4[1,LMM])

Comment: @texdr.aft Thank you, that's impressive! Alas, it is written in the assembly language.

Comment: I just think it's awesome. As for myself, I used Nassi-Shneiderman printouts for all my Assembler sources. So it would have been interesting to see how they went ahead t analyse it into flow charts.

Comment: @Raffzahn It turns out that `FLOWER` is not that impressive. For a maze of `GOTO`, it prints only unconnected triangles with label numbers, unlike `FORFLO`  which draws intersecting arrows on the right, or `FLODIA` which uses letters A and V intead.

Comment: Ah. ok. still. It's the kind of tools I love, as they are a real improvement for programming thruput. independent of language.

Comment: Historical note: An early program for automatically formatting flow charts (though not based on the actual control flow of the input source), as an aid to program documentation, was [described by Donald Knuth in 1963](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/367593.367620) (“Computer-drawn flowcharts”). I'm bringing this up because the format used by Knuth was based on Russian publications; he cites a book about programming the BESM.

Comment: @texdr.aft Perhaps, there was a mechanism to switch these flow-charting tools to that style by specifying particularly formatted comments; thus, documentation or source would be helpful.

Comment: Found a mention of FLODIA in a book called “Software Development Tools” by Raymond C. Houghton, but it references a publication that I can't find: https://books.google.com/books?id=Ll6zvtXTFpoC&pg=RA6-PA45&lpg=RA6-PA45&dq=fortran+%22flodia%22&source=bl&ots=lPfZB2QJon&sig=ACfU3U1SKSqx00V6RcXSXqXDgo0lWHREXw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz2b3ej4v5AhXymGoFHT3BD78Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=fortran%20%22flodia%22&f=false

Comment: @texdr.aft Interesting; in the book it is mentioned that the charts were plotted; then, apparently, either the BESM-6 version, or already the CERN version had the output part recoded for a line printer.

Comment: Both FLODIA and TIDY are mentioned in https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nbsspecialpublication500-88.pdf (NBS Special Publication 500-88 Software Development Tools dated March 1982), but that is just a list of a bunch of software tools with no descriptions (sigh).

Comment: @JonCuster I expect more luck in the [CERN Computer Newsletter](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/search?cc=CNL+Issues), but perusing a hundred of newsletters would take time (their older PDFs are not searchable).

Comment: @JonCuster http://cds.cern.ch/record/1292403/files/n-90.pdf mentions adding `TIDY` to the library but provides no details. It likely comes from CDC, as it is referred to as `7600TIDY`.

Comment: The book mentioned by @texdr.aft on Google books says FLODIA was a product of TRW Simulation Software in Redondo Beach, CA (and one could contact a J D Oliver - good luck with that!). A 'general purpose functional flowcharting program which automatically generates flow diagrams according to user specifications." Sent to a 12 or 30 inch Calcomp plotter. Editing feature, etc.